# How to call the method for all objects in the list using all cores?

Tags: python, multithreading, loops

There is a list of some objects which have some method `f()`.
This is the calling method `f()` for all objects in the list.

```
for item in items:
    item.f()
```

`f()` works independently for all objects. So it can be called for several objects in the same time.
How can I rewrite this code to use all the cores?

Comment: either use the `multiprocessing` module or even better: If possible and compatible with `numba`, translating all methods to numba and calling the loop from within a numba jitted function will increase the performance vastly.

Answer (score 0):

In cpython threads are not executed in parallel, so you have to use processes or async. You could use the `multiprocessing.pool` or the `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` library and then use the map function to execute the function on all objects. Be careful, if you set max_workers equal or hight than the number of CPU cores other programs might experience lag.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers) as executor:
    result =  executor.map(lambda x: x.f(), items)
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/WEPN1WN8. #1 Works. #2 Doesn't. What can be a reason?

Comment: Probably because of the lambda. Try using a dedicated function.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/b4XH3uMz now works but wrong. Fuction is not calling

Comment: Convert the result to list. It should work then: result = executor.map... result = list(result)